# Calculate throughput on a rolling total

Tags: linux, bash, math

I'm not sure if it's the lack of caffeine in my system or not, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the correct way of doing this is (math).

I've got a script that records the values of a parsed ethtool -S every 'x' (6 during this test) seconds until it's manually stopped. I've got the code on how to calculate iterations etc, but I can't figure out how to correctly calculate average bytes per second.

Here's what the output looks like:

```
Fri Jun  8 23:48:35 GMT 2012 {{{
============== Network Statistics ===============
IFNAME     rx_bytes        tx_bytes
eth0      27840111418      3083391508
eth4      6153013050      18478875401
eth5      686368648      238683883
eth6      53863181321      2119523154
eth7      23127231747      84602654827
eth8      399517273166      1686004510

Fri Jun  8 23:48:41 GMT 2012 {{{
============== Network Statistics ===============
IFNAME     rx_bytes        tx_bytes
eth0      27840118248      3083392896
eth4      6153014438      18478876789
eth5      686370036      238685271
eth6      53863182709      2119524542
eth7      23127238019      84602660337
eth8      399519325260      1686018706
```

As we can see the bytes have all incremented, and I'm going to have thousands of iterations of this.

What's the *correct* way of totally these numbers on a per interface basis and calculating the average bytes per second ( I'll eventually move it to mbps via * 0.00000762939453).

Everything I've tried has so far failed...miserably :\

Thank you for your time/patience/assistance!

Edit::
What I currently *think* I need to do is remove the original value for rx/tx bytes to normalize the data. My current (ugly) string for pulling the initial sum is this:

```
int1_rx_bytes=`cat $logfile | grep $int1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {printf "%f", sum}'`
```

Where would I put the original number there for subtraction purposes? For reference, I've got a variable named $int1_orig_rx_bytes already

Comment: I'm thinking I'm going to have to subtract the original total from every addition, but I'm not entirely sure that's going to do it. What do you guys think?

Comment: Not sure I've understood the question, but it sounds like you might be wanting to calculate the 'average or the average' ie. take each interface, calculate average (rx_bytes/6), sum these averages then take another average ie. sum_averages/number of interfaces seen. Alternately, for a overall system average, wouldn't you just sum the rx_bytes+tx_bytes and divide by 6?

Comment: Why don't you divide by `2^17` (131072) instead of multiplying by that awful string of digits?

Comment: @Dennis, I find it gives it a sense of flair :) In all seriousness, I have no valid reason. I'm going to use your technique

Comment: @Pete I need to take the info from ethtool -S and collect it over time x. I then need to calculate the average mbps from said total, which proves difficult since the original value is there. What's the easiest way to remove it?

Comment: @Numpty: Ah I see. Wouldn't you simply load the reported values into two array (maps) keyed by interface and subtract them eg. etho0[1]-eth0[0] etc?. These could be captured in an output file and processed. As you get new input (running ethtool again), remove the first ethtool capture, and add the next. What language are you using to do this? You can use awk as suggested if you're an expert, but it might be simpler in a quick Perl script or a *nix commmand line program written in eg. C++ or C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both scripts are untested.

For a moving average:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    period = 10
    pcount=1
}
NR == 1 {
    baserx = $2
    basetx = $3
}
{
    rx[$1, pcount] = $2 - baserx
    tx[$1, pcount] = $3 - basetx
    ifaces[$1]
    if (c >= period) {
        rxsum = txsum = 0
        for (iface in ifaces) {
            for (i = 1; i <= period; i++) {
                rxsum += rx[iface, i]
                txsum += tx[iface, i]
            }
            print iface, rxsum / period, txsum / period
        }
    } else {
        c++
    }
    pcount = (pcount + 1) % period + 1
}'
```

**Edit:**

For an average of all entries:

```
awk '
NR == 1 {
    baserx = $2
    basetx = $3
}
{
    rx[$1] += $2 - baserx
    tx[$1] += $3 - basetx
}
END {
    for (iface in rx) {
        print iface, rx[iface] / NR, tx[iface] / NR
    }
}'
```

The order that entries will be output is not guaranteed. If you have `gawk` you can add a sort function that will take care of that or you can use the `sort` utility.

**Edit 2:**

This corrects all kinds of problems with the second version above.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFMT = "%.4f"
    }

    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ { next }

    ! ($1 in prevrx) {
        prevrx[$1] = $2
        prevtx[$1] = $3
        next
    }
    {
        count[$1]++
        drx = $2 - prevrx[$1]
        dtx = $3 - prevtx[$1]
        rx[$1] += drx
        tx[$1] += dtx
        prevrx[$1] = $2
        prevtx[$1] = $3
    }
    END {
        for (iface in rx) {
            print iface, rx[iface] / count[iface], tx[iface] / count[iface]
        }
}'
```

Comment: I hope your end result doesn't wind up as a mish-mash of small scripts piping into each other when it could easily be a single, elegant, cohesive program written in AWK, Python or Perl.

Comment: Surprisingly my last thread you helped out on was for a different set of scripts. This is just one collecting data, and one analysing it post-mortem. Also, I'd love to use python, however it's simply not available in this environment. Bash only (and old at that).
Also, I'm pretty horrendous with AWK. Would you mind explaining how that works? Thanks for the help (again)

Comment: Also, looking at it more closely it seems to be what I'm doing already, which produces numbers which are too high to be correct. I believe this is due to the original value being added for each succession>
What I've got now is (faux code):
`codeint1_rx_sum / iterations / time 
int1_tx_sum / iterations / time 
int1_rx_sum + int1_tx_sum = total throughput. 

`
This is completely wrong (far too high)

Comment: @Numpty: The last line is (part of) the key to this working. It makes pcount wrap from 1 to `period` and back around to 1. That means the 11th (in the case of `period = 10`) entry overwrites the first (effectively "subtracting" it). **Note:** It's possible I misunderstood what you want. My script calculates a *moving* average. What I now think you want is to either see the deltas or a moving average of the deltas or something along those lines.

Comment: I think what I had originally was a SMA, however you're right, I just couldn't put it into words properly. I need an average of the deltas between all the values. That way the delta being 8000 bytes (or whatever it ends up being) is going to result in the actual average throughput for that time. Thank you :)

Comment: @Numpty: so you want a moving average or an average of all values at the end?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what to call it. I'm going to try and explain it better. I need to calculate the throughput of an interface with ethtool. ethtool outputs a total of all bytes that the device has currently processed. I only care about the bytes that occur while the script is running. I need to calculate the average increase (throughput) in bytes over the time from the point the script begins running. In my mind, this means excluding the existing counter completely and only using what's changed since then (delta). Let me know if that makes more sense

Comment: @Numpty: OK, I've got that part. Do you want to average **all** the entries for a particular interface during the *whole* time the script runs (printing one line per interface at the very end), or do you want a *moving* average in which the most recent, say, 10 entries are averaged and a line of output is printed for every line of input except for the first, say, 9?

Comment: Ah, sorry - An average of all the entries for a specific interface is what I'm going for. Thank you

Comment: Great, thank you Dennis. I will try and test it out shortly (it's getting late though) :)

Comment: Hi Dennis - I was finally able to get some time to test this out today, and it seems the numbers it's giving are incorrect unfortunately.
I've pasted a log containing the output taken 17 times over 17 seconds here: http://pastebin.com/p1pwZeBN
This is the output the awk you provided supplies (I added in the math for division by 131072):
`code

DMZ 34516 210004
 0 0
Internal 404583 206618
Lan1 285.656 7734.81
Lan2 168213 5110.22
Lan3 108.396 71.9278
External 192801 392305`

Comment: @Numpty: I'm sorry. There are all kinds of problems with that script. I've added a new version. Please try it. Also compare the results with and without the `next` statement.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. That's looking a lot better. I'll have to test this out on a larger sample to be sure, but I've got a few questions for you:
1) How does this account / differentiate between the time for iterations (1 second vs 60 etc)
2) What should I expect to see with and without 'next'?

Thanks again for all of your help :)

Comment: @Numpty: With the **second** `next` it uses the count of intervals for the average (n-1). Without it, it uses the count of samples (n). (The *first* `next` is used to skip blank lines.) There's nothing in my script that accounts for the length of the interval. The average is calculated as bytes only and is intended to be interpreted as "bytes/interval" with an unspecified "interval". Additional code would be required to either parse the interval value out of the timestamps or to accept it as an argument. Also, the code doesn't handle any non-data lines (headers, etc.) except for blank ones.

Comment: Thank for the explanation, it looks like it's working perfectly! Thank you *so* much Dennis. You just made my day/week/month :)