# Calculate largest delta (throughput spikes) with bash

Tags: linux, bash, math

Thanks to the epic work of Dennis Williamson, I am now able to calculate average throughput for an infinite number of NICs via ethtool -S outputs. The details of which can be found here:

[Calculate throughput on a rolling total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957483/calculate-throughput-on-a-rolling-total)

Now, an average throughput is an extremely useful sizing tool, however I also need to determine the maximum bursts of traffic during the same time period. Accounting for 95% of the traffic is all well and good, however if I can't get an easy/accurate measurement on the maximum burst each NIC sees I can't account for the other 5% of the time.

Dennis wrote it all in awk which I'm unfortunately not very well versed in. I haven't been able to modify his existing code to do what I want. Is it possible to do this in bash?

For reference, you can find a sample log file we need to parse here:
http://pastebin.com/p1pwZeBN

Dennis' code is here:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    OFMT = "%.4f"
}

/^[[:blank:]]*$/ { next }

! ($1 in prevrx) {
    prevrx[$1] = $2
    prevtx[$1] = $3
    next
}
{
    count[$1]++
    drx = $2 - prevrx[$1]
    dtx = $3 - prevtx[$1]
    rx[$1] += drx
    tx[$1] += dtx
    prevrx[$1] = $2
    prevtx[$1] = $3
}
END {
    for (iface in rx) {
        print iface, rx[iface] / count[iface], tx[iface] / count[iface]
    }
}'
```

Thank you for all of your help! :)

Edit:: As an example to help elaborate on what I'd like to see. If the new script can parse the log file (for DMZ inbound let's say), it should determine that the largest delta was between lines 121 and 113 IE:

```
DMZ      36195731362 vs DMZ      36195255177
= 668659 / 131072 = 5.1~mbps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but a few small changes should work:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    OFMT = "%.4f"
}

/^[[:blank:]]*$/ { next }

! ($1 in prevrx) {
    prevrx[$1] = $2
    prevtx[$1] = $3
    next
}
{
    count[$1]++
    drx = $2 - prevrx[$1]
    dtx = $3 - prevtx[$1]
    rx[$1] += drx
    tx[$1] += dtx
    prevrx[$1] = $2
    prevtx[$1] = $3
    if (drx > maxdrx[$1]) {
        maxdrx[$1] = drx
    }
    if (dtx > maxdtx[$1]) {
        maxdtx[$1] = dtx
    }
}
END {
    for (iface in rx) {
        print iface, rx[iface] / count[iface], tx[iface] / count[iface], maxdrx[iface], maxdtx[iface]
    }
}'
```

Comment: That was quick. I need to put you on payroll apparently :) I'll test it out and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: According to my tests it looks like it's 100% accurate. Thanks (again) Dennis!

Comment: Actually, running tests on gigantic files seem to produce some erroneous numbers. Most are realistic (referring to the 'max' numbers), however some are 5-6 times that of the interface's physical speed.

Is there a way to debug this? Running it with -vx unfortunately doesn't tell me where it's pulling those numbers from

Comment: @Numpty: Are the erroneous numbers the averages or the maximums? If it's the maximums, you can put something like `if (drx > threshold) {print "***", NR, $0}` (and one for tx), substituting some value you choose for "threshold", after the assignment statements as a diagnostic and run it against an abbreviated data file which has suspect data in it. Then you can examine your data around the indicated line.

Comment: It's the maximums that look off - I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: That did it. There are some rather large leaps in data, such as:
`code External      3685324972      4259307582 to External      3734273199      4281919879` in 1 second, when the link is 100mbps which equates to about 370~ mbps. Is there a way of placing in an error check to have a limit of interface speed ( I can hardcode it in the script). IE: If delta > link speed -> skip

Comment: I'm going to assume these are caused by lack of CPU time to run ethtool, and it gets pushed back for a few seconds until there are cycles available for it.

Comment: @Numpty: `if (drx > linkspeed) { next }` won't do it alone. You'll need to deduct the excess or something like that.

Comment: Yep, that seemed to do it. Thanks again Dennis!

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate the data gathering from processing. Get the data using bash tools, etc. But then analyze using a tool better suited for data vis / processing, etc. Matlab, Mathematica, Octave, R, Scipy, Maybe even JMP.

It's not that the awk here isn't impressive, it's just that what do you do when something goes wrong, and you have to debug that script. Languages tailored for data processing and analysis are going to have many more tools to help you out if/when you're in this scenario.

Comment: Love to, but the data can't technically leave the device - it has to be analysed there unfortunately.